# SQL Query to transpose table based on year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I have a table in SQL Server that has specific years in a column with values in another column. I would like to make a column for each year and enter its relevant value into the relevant year's column.

I would like to create a view that will show the results but I am not sure how to do this with SQL.

Original table structure:

| ID | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 748 |
| 2 | 2018 | 1613 |
| 3 | 2028 | 2493 |
| 4 | 2038 | 2074 |
| 5 | 2048 | 688 |
| 6 | 2016 | 818 |
| 7 | 2018 | 2068 |
| 8 | 2028 | 1301 |
| 9 | 2038 | 1726 |
| 10 | 2048 | 661 |
| 11 | 2016 | 1413 |
| 12 | 2018 | 1063 |
| 13 | 2028 | 1815 |
| 14 | 2038 | 2546 |
| 15 | 2048 | 1574 |
| 16 | 2016 | 861 |
| 17 | 2018 | 1676 |
| 18 | 2028 | 1316 |
| 19 | 2038 | 1498 |
| 20 | 2048 | 1557 |

Required structure for view:

| ID | Value_2016 | Value_2018 | Value_2028 | Value_2038 | Value_2048 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 748 | 1613 | 2493 | 2074 | 688 |
| 2 | 818 | 2068 | 1301 | 1726 | 661 |
| 3 | 1413 | 1063 | 1815 | 2546 | 1574 |
| 4 | 861 | 1676 | 1316 | 1498 | 1557 |

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: This is called a [`pivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16). Good answers at [stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ID,
MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN T.YEAR=2016 THEN T.VALUE
      ELSE 0.00
    END
  )AS VALUE_2016,
MAX(
  CASE
     WHEN T.YEAR=2018 THEN T.VALUE
     ELSE 0.00
  END
 )AS VALUE_2018, 
MAX(
   CASE
     WHEN T.YEAR=2028 THEN T.VALUE
     ELSE 0.00
    END
  )AS VALUE_2028
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
GROUP BY T.ID
```

You can also try "old-style"-pivot as above.
If you need dynamic number of columns, please goggle for "dynamic pivot in SQL Server"